# SharePoint 2013 Installation Error

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, configuration, installation, configuration-wizard

I have a problem in installing SharePoint foundation 2013 on my Window Server 2012 R2. When i run SharePoint Product Preparation tool , i am getting error like "the tool was unable to install application server and web server (IIS) role.". please someone help me to out of these problem

Comment: Did u run the pre-requisite installer ? Share the setup log and check if you have internet connectivity incase you havent installed the prequisite binaries offline..